# Does "vanilla" Ruby dotenv pick up any file other than .env?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, ruby-dotenv

I want to use environment-specific variables in my non-Rails Ruby application.

I tried different file names like `.env.test.local`, `.env.local`, `.env.test`

I tried using the `Dotenv.load` and `require 'dotenv/load'` approaches

This is how I wrap the task

```rb
require 'rspec'
require 'rack/test'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
require 'dotenv/tasks'

task test: :dotenv do
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec).run_task(verbose: true)
end
```

This is my server

```rb
require 'dotenv/load'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader' if development?

set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

get ENV['API_URL'] do
  'Hello World!'
end
```

My `.env.test` file

```
API_URL=/api/v1
```

### Expected behavior

The API_URL variable should be available to the code run by the `:test` task (using `bundle exec rake test`).

### Observed behavior

An error caused because `ENV['API_URL']` is null.

```
/Users/mariogil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby -I/Users/mariogil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib:/Users/mariogil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rspec-support-3.8.0/lib /Users/mariogil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb

An error occurred while loading ./spec/server_spec.rb.
Failure/Error:
  get ENV['API_URL'] do
    'Hello World!'
  end

TypeError:
  NilClass can't be coerced into Mustermann::Pattern
# /Users/mariogil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann.rb:73:in `new'
# /Users/mariogil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sinatra-2.0.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1641:in `compile'
# /Users/mariogil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sinatra-2.0.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1629:in `compile!'
# /Users/mariogil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sinatra-2.0.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1604:in `route'
# /Users/mariogil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sinatra-2.0.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1386:in `get'
# /Users/mariogil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sinatra-2.0.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1925:in `block (2 levels) in delegate'
# ./lib/server.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/server_spec.rb:6:in `require'
# ./spec/server_spec.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00026 seconds (files took 0.18951 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples

/Users/mariogil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby -I/Users/mariogil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib:/Users/mariogil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rspec-support-3.8.0/lib /Users/mariogil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb failed
```

[See the repo](https://github.com/chioi/ruby-dotenv-not-loading-in-test-env)

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this workaround

```rb
require 'dotenv'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader' if development?
Dotenv.load(".env.#{ENV['APP_ENV']}") # Remember to set your app environment

set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

get ENV['API_URL'] do
  'Hello World!'
end
```

It only works for `.env.<ENVIROMENT>` files. Maybe this could be wrapped in a function but I definitely would like this to be handled by the gem as in Rails applications, it makes more sense to me.

Comment: Nothing in the project README mentions `ENV['APP_ENV']`; the only mention of environment-specific config files is in relation to `dotenv-rails` and `Rails.env`. After a little research, I see this issue has been raised before, and one of the library's authors suggested something very similar to your solution above: https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/issues/290